# How large a file size from GCS can handle in Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to transfer a >=4 GB of data from GCS to BigQuery using Cloud Function in GCP. Is it possible to do that? I tried creating a temporary 5 gb data file using `mkfile` commands and tried uploading to GCS. It takes very long time and still does not upload. Does this mean that GCS cannot handle more than certain file size ..

In the documentation I refered:https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas ,I got to know that GCS handle upto 5 TiB of data. Then why it takes very long time to upload 5 GB of data.

Is it possible to handle more than 4 GB of data to transfer from GCS to BigQuery via Cloud Function?How many GB data can CF and GCS handle? Is there any possible way to reduce the data size via any services? Can I get any documentation related to the limit for the data that CF and GCS can handle?

Comment: 1) Ask one question per post. 2) Cloud Functions does not have disk storage. You have access to the **/tmp** directory which is actually a ramdisk. The maximum RAM size is 8 GB. I have not tested trying to load a file into memory or /tmp larger than a few dozen MB. 3) IMHO Functions is the wrong service to use for processing anything over 100 MB per invocation. 4) Your question does not provide details or context. Cloud Dataflow might be a better solution since you mention GCS and BiqQuery.

Comment: Is there any limit in the data size the cloud function can handle?

Comment: There is no data size limit. It is a function of RAM, network bandwidth, and maximum execution time.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the file size using Dataflow?

Comment: When you ask questions, you need to provide details. The answer depends on the data and what transformations you plan to perform.

Comment: My requirement is to upload a file in GCS (5GB) in csv format.I will write a cloud function that triggers when a file is uploaded in GCS and then the data in the file will be transferred to BigQuery.I want to know if the cloud function will be able to handle 5 GB of data?if not,is there a way to reduce the file size using Dataflow or any other alternative?

Comment: Create well defined questions. Stack Overflow is not a chat box.

Comment: In your question, can you be precise on what you want to achieve? Do you want to load a 5Gb CSV file (stored in GCS) in BigQuery? Or, do you want to load a 5Gb file in Cloud Functions, update/transform it, and load it in BigQuery? The data flow is very important to use the most suitable tools.

Comment: I would guess - the main question - if any transformation (during or before loading) is required or not. Without knowing the context of the task - I would guess in general - a data flow is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence in your question:

> I want to transfer a >=4 GB of data from GCS to BigQuery(BQ)

If we stop right there, you do not need Cloud Function(CF) for the transfer. BQ is totally capable of taking care of ingesting your *BIG* CSV file from GCS (up to 15TB). But you need to trigger this ingestion or more precisely the BQ load job. Here enters Cloud Function. It can be plugged to your bucket. As soon as your file finishes uploading to GCS it will trigger the cloud function that will run the BigQuery Load job.

Below an example of load job to run with CF in python39. **Dont forget to set the `table_id`** And for more information or other languages, you can check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table).

```py
# the file should be named main.py

def load_csv_from_gcs_to_bq(data, _):
    file_name = data["name"]
    bucket_name = data["bucket"]
    # Construct the GCS file uri to load
    uri = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{file_name}"

    from google.cloud import bigquery

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    # TODO: Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    # table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"


    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=True,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    )

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.

    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

    destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

With the `requirements.txt` file

```
google-cloud-bigquery==2.24.0
```

And here the command to deploy the CF (**set YOUR_GCS_BUCKET without gs://**) Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize) for more details.

```
gcloud functions deploy load_csv_from_gcs_to_bq \
--region europe-west1 \
--runtime python39 \
--timeout 300 \
--memory 128 \
--trigger-resource <YOUR_GCS_BUCKET> \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

Once your CSV is loaded in BQ, you can use BQ to do many types of transformation and store the result in new table(s).

But If you need custom and very specific transformation, for the size of your data Dataflow will be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks ..I was looking for this

Answer (score -1):

If your upload to GCS is slow you can try:

- Upload with gsutil with the -m switch to use more than one process (`gsutil cp -m file.csv gs://bucket/destination.
- Split the CSV in several files with a random name (like `gs://bucket/0021asdcq1231scjhas.csv` and upload in parallel using more that one process for each file. This way you'll use more than one ingestion server in cloud storage.

Comment: However, the OP is reading data from Cloud Storage. The HTTP body limit does not apply.

Comment: True, but is also considering to push the data directly to a cloud function, then send it to BQ.

Comment: There is no **push** of Cloud Storage object data to cloud functions. Your comment about sending to BQ does not apply either. If you are thinking events as in Pub/Sub, the event does not include the Cloud Storage object in the event.

Comment: I don't think that the 10Mb limit is relevant to the question above... In addition, it may not be possible to split the original csv file into chunks (without "reading it), as the boundary should be between "lines".